# Why would a dynamically-created IFRAME cause the page "stop" button to activate in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I'm creating, appending, and writing to an IFRAME in JavaScript to display some HTML that must be "sandboxed" from the rest of the page.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
document.getElement('myParentDiv').appendChild(iframe)
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(myHtml)
```

This generally works fine, except in Firefox -- and no other browser -- this "activates" the "page stop" button.

Normally, when a page is loaded, there's a Refresh button in the toolbar. But as soon as this code runs, the Refresh button turns into a Stop button ( a big "X"), as if to say "the page is loading, click here to stop it." The button never goes back to Refresh.

Again, this only happens in Firefox. As near as I can tell, it causes no ill effects. It's just annoying.

Should I be telling my code to "stop" or something? When I do the `document.write`, does Firefox think there's more coming?  Is there a way to tell it, "okay, the document render is complete..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doc.close()` should fix the issue.

```
<a id="myParentDiv"></a>
<script>
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
document.getElementById('myParentDiv').appendChild(iframe)
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.write("ff");
doc.close();
</script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Weird that Firefox is the only browser that has an issue with it.